# download a file to project resources

Tags: vb.net

i use `Visual Basic 2008`.
hello is it possible to download a file directly to project resources, or to import file to resources on running vb 2008 application.

**for example**
i have : www.example.com/file.ext
and i want to download it, but not to `C:\` or `C:\` drives, but to `My.Resources.file`... is it possible?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn’t possible. Resources in your program are *fixed*: once your program is running, it cannot modify its resources.

Apart from that you can use the [`WebClient.DownloadData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f.aspx) method to download data into a variable without saving it to disc.

Comment: thanks for the : WebClient.DownloadData , but it is possible to save data from .exe file into a variable and then change resource ( for example i have in resources : file.exe ) , for example : My.Resources.file = downloadData

Comment: @John No, that’s not possible. As I’ve said, resources are fixed in a running program.

Comment: ok thanks, but can i use My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes() to write a .exe file from downloaded data ( variable with data )?